# Java : PhantomJS can't find xpath elements

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I need to use headless automation for a website to get some information from it, I used PhantomJS as it was the obvious solution.

But the problem is that my driver can't find any of my xpath or cssSelectors.
Code used to run perfectly on firefoxDriver

I'm using :

- Selenium 3.0.1
- PhantomJS 1.9.8

Heres my code (sorry I had to hide some of my code)

```
@Before
public static WebDriver setUp() throws Exception {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
    capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();       
    capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "phantomjs.exe");
    capabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.binary.path", "phantomjs.exe");

    PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities); 
    String baseURL = "url";
    driver.get(baseURL);
    System.out.println("Loading page");
    return driver;

}

@Test
public static void test(WebDriver driver, String login, String password) throws InterruptedException, IOException 
{
    CookieHandler.addCookie(driver); //function that add a cookie to my driver
    CookieHandler.printAllCookies(driver); //just to verify cookie is added

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement LoginButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("somexpath")));
    LoginButton.click();

    // ... some other treatement but code blocked here
}
```

I searched the whole day, tried HtmlUnitDriver ... no solution can be found

Any help ?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE :**

Can't access any form with PhantomJS

Comment: make sure the element is loaded, available and visible at the time you are trying to test that element.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas : I use wait until, which make it, as I think visible and clickable, I even made a screenshot of my PhantomJS driver before clicking, and as I saw the page is completely loaded